# Long violin pegs

Tags: violin

I have recently purchased an old violin (1805 on the label) to restore myself.

I am, however, surprised by the long pegs it has; see the the image.

Have you ever seen such long pegs?

They look quite old so I would say they are the original ones. Is it possible that they are from a viola or something else?

What do you think?

[image: Long violin pegs]

Answer (score 3):

As long as the pegs still fit and tune well, they are fine.  This is what happens to pegs after time: the holes wear larger, the pegs smaller, and they therefore stick further in.  At some point you will need either new pegs or (depending on how large the holes are) also the holes bushed out (made smaller with inserts).  But they look still useable to me.

Btw- the pegs are not that old, and perhaps the violin also not.

The peg heads are not as flat as would be usual for 200 year old plus pegs, and they also have the modern taper of 1:30 rather than the old 1:20. And while I of course can't tell how old the violin is from just this photo, statistically speaking there are probably ten times as many newer instruments with false labels than violins really made in 1805